# Planificar propriedades em uma única tabela

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, migrations

Considere as seguintes classes:

```
public class Pessoa
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Nome { get; set; }
   public Telefone Telefone { get; set; }
}

public class Telefone
{
   public string Numero { get; set; }
   public string Descricao { get; set; }
   public Operadora Operadora { get; set; }
}

public class Operadora
{
   public string Descricao { get; set; }
   public string Codigo { get; set; }
}
```

No banco de dados (SQL Server) quero ter a seguinte tabela:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| PessoaDados                                                             |
+----+------+--------+-----------+---------------------+------------------+
| Id | Nome | Numero | Descricao | Operadora_Descricao | Operadora_Codigo |
+----+------+--------+-----------+---------------------+------------------+
```

Estou usando Migrations do Entity Framework 6, mas ao rodar o comando de update, o Entity reclama da classe Telefone não ter *Id*.

Pesquisei por *DataAnnotations*, mas não encontrei nada que pudesse ajudar.

Utilizando CodeFirst, é possível planificar tabelas da maneira como estou tentando?

Comment: a versão é 6 ou Core?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic atualizei a pergunta com a versão. Seria o EF 6 mesmo.

Comment: E ai amigo testou a resposta???

Answer (score 0):

Sim é possível, tem que mapear os campos tudo na mesma configuração da classe `Pessoa`, mas, isso tem que ser feito pela classe de configuração e configurando o método `OnModelCreating` da seguinte forma:

***Classes:***

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public Pessoa()
    {
        Telefone = new Telefone();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }          
    public Telefone Telefone { get; set; }
}

public class Telefone
{
    public Telefone()
    {
        Operadora = new Operadora();
    }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }            
    public Operadora Operadora { get; set; }
}

public class Operadora
{   
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Codigo { get; set; }        
}
```

***Observação:*** na classe `Pessoa` e `Telefone` seus membros que são classes são instanciados no construtor para que não aconteça exceção nas atualizações.

```
public class DatabaseContext: DbContext
{
    public const string ConnectionString = " *** ";

    public DbSet<Pessoa> Pessoas { get; set; }

    public DatabaseContext():
        base(ConnectionString)
    {            
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>()
                .HasKey(x => x.Id)
                .Property(x => x.Id)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>()
                .Property(x => x.Nome)
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>()
                .Property(x => x.Telefone.Descricao)
                .HasColumnName("Descricao")
                .HasMaxLength(100);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>()
                .Property(x => x.Telefone.Numero)
                .HasColumnName("Numero")
                .HasMaxLength(100);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>()
                .Property(x => x.Telefone.Operadora.Descricao)
                .HasColumnName("Operadora_Descricao")
                .HasMaxLength(100);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>()
                .Property(x => x.Telefone.Operadora.Codigo)
                .HasColumnName("Operadora_Codigo")
                .HasMaxLength(100);
    }
}
```

No caso acima tudo foi configurado para `Entity` `Pessoa` e em cada propriedade crie as configurações como foi pedido na pergunta.

Answer (score -1):

Neste ponto eu consigo ver 3 observações:

1. Do jeito que a classe está declarada, 01 pessoa terá apenas 01 telefone, quando na verdade, imagino que deveria ser vários. Para este caso, em pessoa o correto seria você ter um `List<Telefone>`, com sua devida inicialização no construtor.
2. Você irá precisar do id em Telefone e Operadora, pois o code first (pelo meu simples conhecimento) irá criar três tabelas, todas devidamente relacionadas.
3. Como seriam criadas três tabelas, uma saída para você seria criar uma view da forma que você espera, mas se tratando de EF, quando uma busca por ID for solicitada, o objeto inteiro será carregado, com os telefones e a Operadora, mas para tal, será necessário configurar o lazyloading.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, mas neste exemplo não estou levando em conta a modelagem, apenas se o Entity Framework possui ou não o recurso de planificar mais de uma classe em uma só tabela.